# How to write a complex query using `expr` in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a bit complicated query to the MongoDB and I honestly don't know how to write it correctly. In SQL pseudocode it's something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Something
WHERE 
   (IF Item.NestedItem THEN NULL ELSE Item.NestedItem.Id) == 'f4421f9e-5962-4c68-8049-a45600f36f4b'
OR (IF Item.NestedItem THEN NULL ELSE Item.NestedItem.OtherId) == 'd6b799dc-f464-4919-8435-a7b600cc408a'
```

I succeeded in writing IF as

```
{ "$cond" : [{ "$eq" : ["$Item.NestedItem", null] }, null, "$Item.NestedItem.Id"] }
{ "$cond" : [{ "$eq" : ["$Item.NestedItem", null] }, null, "$Item.NestedItem.OtherId"] }
```

But now I'm not sure how to compare them to constants and then join. I'm trying to write a translator from SQL-like language to MongoDb and this is example of query I cannot translate. I want something like

```
{ "$and" : 
    { "$eq" : { "$cond" : [{ "$eq" : ["$Item.NestedItem", null] }, null, "$Item.NestedItem.Id"] }, "f4421f9e-5962-4c68-8049-a45600f36f4b" },
    { "$eq" : { "$cond" : [{ "$eq" : ["$Item.NestedItem", null] }, null, "$Item.NestedItem.OtherId"] }, "d6b799dc-f464-4919-8435-a7b600cc408a" } }
```

But it's an invalid query as I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) is a aggregation expression, you need to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#using-expr-with-conditional-statements) before `$and` operation, in your SQL query you have user `OR` so just updating in query $and to $or

- corrected `$eq` syntax after `$or`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$Item.NestedItem", null] }, 
                  null, 
                  "$Item.NestedItem.Id"
                ]
              },
              "f4421f9e-5962-4c68-8049-a45600f36f4b"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$Item.NestedItem", null] },
                  null,
                  "$Item.NestedItem.OtherId"
                ]
              },
              "d6b799dc-f464-4919-8435-a7b600cc408a"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2KT5na38V9n)

Comment: Right, you gave me some insights. Thanks

Comment: Is `Item` array or object?

Comment: An object. It looks like the query is pretty simple and the only question is how do I translate it via primitives I have. But it's unrelated to Mongo itself, so I think I just accept your answer and gone playing with it.

Comment: Okay good, have just updated and confirmed in playground, you can check if its help you.